# What is auto Automatic-Brace-Completion for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, autocomplete, ide

How to turn it off has been asked. But *what's the point* in it to begin with? After all - when I want to continue after the braces (or parentheses) - I have to press *some* key anyway. So how can I use this to my benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the premise to be slightly questionable.  Yes, there are instances where if you want to keep typing lines in sequential order the automatic brace completion probably gains little to nothing.  However, I'd suggest that you (I) frequently program in non-linear lines.  Some examples:

1. When you hit the end of a method, you are often going to jump to some other file to continue, so you don't have to add the ending brace of a method.
2. When you are modifying code inside of a method, you often times are just adding a couple lines of code.
3. Even when creating new files, I rarely start with a blank file, either I'm using a code snippet, or copying some other file as a starting point.  Further, even if you're starting with a blank file, probably the first few lines that you're adding are `namespace {` and `class {`.  Right there are two closing braces that you don't have to type because you're likely not going to be adding code after them.

And I'm sure there are more instances.  Off the top of my head, I'd guess that I write continuous lines of code pretty infrequently.  That may just be me though.

Comment: 1 - Yes. 2 - That would have to be parentheses you're talking about; At least in C# - I'd still have to add the semi-colon so I'd also have to "add" the closing parenthesis. 3 - I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: OK. I see your edit. But I rarely if ever start out with a blank file (as you mentioned) and therefore I _don't_ have to type those in.

Comment: @ispiro For 2, I'm saying that there are many cases where you go into a method and add a single `if { }`, `for { }` or some other type of block.  In this case, you just add the single block and move on to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Different people have different preferences, but features like this in a code editor enable faster writing of code to the well-practiced user.  For instance, when creating a function, typing

```
void foo(){ <enter>
```

will create the following code

```
void foo () {
    <cursor here>
}
```

allowing you to quickly create something without worrying about typing out the syntax of the language (as much).  The same should work with `if`, `while`, etc.

Like myself, programmers tend to be lazy (Doh! >.<) so even a couple fewer key presses is a glorious thing.

EDIT:

There is a comment that this doesn't actually save key presses, so I will attempt to clarify what I mean.

QUALITATIVELY: this is what I meant by "people have different preferences".  Some people probably don't care about this feature, but some people find it very useful.  Some people think that coding with auto-completion features ***feels*** more fluid... once you get used to it, it's hard to code without it.

QUANTITATIVELY: consider the following class wrapped within a namespace with and without auto-completion of braces and tabs.

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
\t  public class DoStuff {
\t  \t  private int myPrivate;
\t  \t
\t  \t  public DoStuff() {
\t  \t  \t  myPrivate = 73; // 0x1001001 yay palidromes!
\t  \t  }
\t  \t
\t  \t  public int GetMyStuff() {
\t  \t  \t  return myPrivate;
\t  \t  }
\t  }
}
```

ok, so if all of the "\t"s are tabs, then that's 22 (I hope I can count!) tabs, and 3 curly braces at the end for a grand total of 25 key presses.  Not much, but not bad for such a small file and a simple feature.

What I really like about auto-completion of braces is what can happen when it is combined with more advanced features and tools.  Depending on your IDE of choice, there may be many tools that let you auto-complete not only braces and parentheses, but keywords, type names, identifiers, etc.  If you implement an interface, for example, there are tools which will *automatically* create an implementation class shell (without any implementations inside the methods), which means that you don't have to write any method declarations at all!

In my opinion, there is a tool out there that will suit any programmer better than a plain text editor.  Just keep trying IDEs and corresponding tools until it ***feels*** right to you, and don't focus on the quantitative measurement of key presses.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If we didn't have brace-completion - it would be exactly the same because when we're done typing - we _usually_ will need to continue after the braces anyway.

Comment: Like I said, people have differing preferences, but typically people find features like this useful.

Comment: `a couple fewer key presses` - Where do I gain that?

Comment: @ispiro Probably you won't gain that nowhere, unless you have to press something in order to indent you code later after pressing the closing brace. But remember, we're not robots, we're not counting mentally every key that we press while we code. The thing is that typing with auto-completion feels more fluid to some people, and that is enough for them.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that when you want to continue after the braces, you will have to press a key as you would have to if the feature didn't exist. However, when you want to type inside the braces or parenthesis, you won't have to type another key, the IDE won't complain about missing braces or parenthesis [and will indent everything correctly]  while you type, and you'll be able to start typing right away.

Also, remember that there are other languages supported by Visual Studio that can, sometimes, take more advantage from this feature. Visual Basic, for example, does not requires that all method calls have parenthesis in them:

```
// This is completely valid in VB
obj.Method1.Method2.Method3()

// So if you open a parenthesis, it is because you probably want to write
// something inside them, like this:
obj.Method1(argument).Method(argument2).Method3(argument3)
```

Comment: I understand your first point - to prevent the squiggly line from appearing. But the second - I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @ispiro Refer to my update :) What I tried to say is: since most of the time in VB you'll be wanting to write inside the parenthesis, VS helps you with that by auto-completing the closing parenthesis and putting the cursor inside them, so you can start typing right away.

Comment: I can do that without auto-completion as well. No gain at all in keystrokes or even their order.

Comment: But you can write faster, think less about syntatic sugar, and help the IDE :)

Comment: `write faster` - In what way? It's _exactly_ the same key sequence! `syntatic sugar` - Just until I close the braces and get it automatically anyway! `help the IDE` - Now you're talking! (Although it's actually the other way around, if at all. But I like that idea :)